# Using for loop name in assignment R

Tags: r

I am trying to use the for loop variables for an assingment in R. Let's say I have a list of 3 strings:

```
fruits = list('apple', 'pear', 'grape')
```

I wish to use these names to assign in a for loop e.g.

```
values = list()
for (name in fruits){
    values <- c(values, name = 5)
}
```

I would want a new list that looks like this:

```
values
apple = 5
pear = 5
grape = 5
```

However what I receieve is this:

```
values
name = 5
name = 5
name = 5
```

Is this possible in R or can this not be done?

Thanks

Comment: what are apple, pear and grape? Are they dataframes?

Comment: Apologies, they are strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign it with `[[]]`:

```
fruits = list("apple"," pear", "grape")

#I wish to use these names to assign in a for loop e.g.

values = list()
for (name in fruits){
    values[[name]] <- c(5)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also some times its easier not to set the names during a loop, but to set the names afterward. So if you have you list already

```
values <- list(5, 5, 5)
# or values <- as.list(rep(5,3))
```

you could do

```
values <- setNames(values, fruits)
```

Or if you are using `Map()` to get a value for each of these inputs, the result will be named for you assuming you pass in a character vector rather than a list. (And if you are just storing names, then a vector is probably better for most things)

```
Map(function(...) 5, as.character(fruits))
# $apple
# [1] 5
# $pear
# [1] 5
# $grape
# [1] 5
```